# Why is Taylor Series necessary for Runge Kutta methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, runge-kutta-methods

I know that the `Runge Kutta` methods are usually derived using Taylor Series expansion.

However, I don't understand why the Taylor Series is even necessary.

If we know $\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=f(t,y(t))$, then I think we should know any   $f(t,y(t))$ at any point.

So, I wonder why we need to take the Taylor series like it does [here](http://courses.washington.edu/amath581/581.pdf):

[image: Taylor series in deriving Runge Kutta]

Comment: Here's an example: let $f(t,y(t)) = \frac{y(t)-t}{y(t)+t}$, so now you know $f(t,y(t))$ at any point. Now suppose $y(0) = 1$. What is $y(1)$? It should be easy since you know $f(t,y(t))$, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand that's because the differential equation is not separable if you have an equation like that.  And I guess you're saying that we only know $f(t,y(t))$ at one point, so we have to just roll with it and use TS around the only $f(t,y(t))$ we know?

Comment: I think you're on the right track now: given any $t$ and $y(t)$ we have a formula for $f(t,y(t))$, but in a typical problem we're given $y(t)$ for only one $t$ (or as you put it, we only know $f(t,y(t))$ at one point), ergo the TS in order to project to some other point. But for 4th order IIRC we also end up doing TS around three other points--anyway the RK4 method evaluates $f$ at four different sets of coordinates, the starting point and three others that you might consider to be "guesses".

Comment: Yes, there are other methods like Runge-Kutta (which is the same as Adams-Bashforth), which require knowing multiple points of $f(t, y(t))$ .  But, in those cases, we are still evaluating TS around *one point* though, right?  What is IIRC?

Comment: IIRC = "if I remember correctly". Actually in this case I think I did not remember correctly! There are three other points where $f$ is evaluated at each step, but in the general case none of them is exactly on the curve $(t,y(t))$, and (hoping I get it right this time) all the Taylor expansions are around the original point.